# Implementing a Javascript plugin system for Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

We are trying to build a Firefox extension where our extension will contain a lot of Javascript plugins. A plugin here is defined as a set of functions that have a main entry point, and they usually provide a response. In OOP they would share the same common abstract class, and a $obj->init()->run()->get() chain is foreseen.

They would be a plugin pool, and each plugin should have a rank, and the exection of the plugins should be performed based on their ranks.

The main questions are:
- how do you create a plugin system in bare Javascript
- are they any open-source plugin systems in JS that may be used for start
- how would you store the plugin pool system and their ranking, and
- how would you make sure that the plugins are executed in the order of their rank

Comment: I guess that you want your plugins to be sandboxed rather than have full privileges?

Comment: @WladimirPalant At this stage I don't care about sandboxing as in the initial phase I will be the only developer, however I need ideas. As I see you are expert in this area. Would you be able to share some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really vague so I will be answering it based on a bunch of guesses. You probably want to do something like what the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) does internally - load your plugins into [sandboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.Sandbox), provide them with some API and call their methods as needed. Also, I guess that you want to use the [null principal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security_check_basics#Principals) to make sure the sandbox doesn't have additional privileges. Something like this should do:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var sandboxProto = {
  rank: -1,
  foo: function()
  {
    throw new Error("Please implement");
  },
  myAPIMethod: function()
  {
    return 5;
  }
};
var sandboxPrincipal = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/nullprincipal;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrincipal);

var plugins = [];

function loadPlugin(url)
{
  try
  {
    var sandbox = Components.utils.Sandbox(sandboxPrincipal, {
      sandboxName: url,
      sandboxPrototype: sandboxProto
    });
    Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(url, sandbox);
    plugins.push(sandbox);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    Components.utils.reportError(e);
  }
}

function callPluginMethod(methodName)
{
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  // Always resort plugins in case their rank changes
  plugins.sort(function(a, b)
  {
    // Make sure that we work with numbers
    var r1 = parseInt(a.rank, 10) || -1;
    var r2 = parseInt(a.rank, 10) || -1;
    return r2 - r1;
  });

  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < plugins.length; i++)
  {
    if (methodName in plugins[i])
    {
      try
      {
        results.push(plugins[i][methodName].apply(plugins[i], args));
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        Components.utils.reportError(e);
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

And a plugin would look like this:

```js
var rank = 1000;

function foo()
{
  return 2 * myAPIMethod();
}
```

So the following code should show you `[10]`:

```js
loadPlugin("chrome://.../content/plugin.js");

var results = callPluginMethod("foo");
alert(results.toSource());
```

As to how your extension would know where to find its plugins - that's an entirely different question and depends largely on the requirements (something that is missing from this question). Note however that subscript loader will only work with local URLs - only plugins will work that are part of your extension or located on user's disk. If the list of plugins is going to be dynamic then you probably want to create a directory for them in user's profile and download them to this directory as required (you should be very careful as to not give these plugins too many privileges then, to avoid security issues).

Comment: We will have these plugins available on server side also, actually they do something with a DOM object. We are wondering if code reuse can be accomplished by having the server side component in Node.JS. As far as you know, can certain Javascript objects be taken from the extension and placed in different JS server and both to have the same functionality?

Comment: Sure they can, as long as the API accessed exists both on client and server. It's probably easiest to provide a `require()` function on client side as per CommonJS. But that's a pretty trivial thing to implement.